# Como puedo mandar el valor de una variable por una url dentro del cuerpo de un mail con html?

Tags: php, html, url

quiero pasar el valor de dos variables por el html que va incrustado en contenido del mail que se envía, tengo 2 botones confirmar y cancelar en el botón confirmar quiero mandar un valor por esa url

el código es el siguiente:

```
$mail = $row["mail"];

$cabeceras = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

//realiza el envio de mail por cada uno de los pacientes consultados a la db
$destino= "mailpruebraxy@gmail.com";//$row["mail"];


//$contenido= "Nombre: " . $paciente ."\nDocumento: " . $documento ."\nPuesto: " . $puesto ."\nProfesional: " . $profesional .  "\nFecha: " . $fecha;
$contenidoHTML=   '<!DOCTYPE html>'.
                    '<html>'.
                      '<head>'.
                      '<meta charset="utf-8">'.
                      '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">'.
                      '<body>'.
                      '<fieldset>'.
                      '<header>'.
                      '<div class="container" "background-color:red;" >'.

                      '</header>'.
                            '<br>';
$contenidoHTML .=   '<div style = "float left">USUARIO : <strong>'.$row["usuario"];'</strong></div><br><br>'.

$contenidoHTML .=   '<div style = "float left">DOCUMENTO : <strong>'.$row["dni"];'</strong></div><br><br>'.
$contenidoHTML .=   '<a href="https://prueba.000webhostapp.com/insertDBYES.php?ide=$row["id"]&estado1=$id"><button>CONFIRMAR</button></a>'.
$contenidoHTML .=   '<a href="https://prueba.000webhostapp.com/insertDBNO.php?ide=<?php echo $id;?>&estado2=<?php echo $estado2?>"><button>CANCELAR</button></a>'.
                    '</center>'.
                    '</fieldset>'.
                    '</body>'.
                    '</html>';
mail($destino,"NOTIFICACION",$contenidoHTML, $cabeceras);
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estás cometiendo varios errores en tu concatenación.

Eso suele ocurrir cuando se mezcla código PHP/HTML, se crea tal confusión que uno termina perdido rápidamente entre tantas aperturas y cierres de bloques, de comillas dobles, de comillas simples, de aperturas y cierres de etiquetas.

Y cuando hay que meterse a analizar ese código, se te van los ánimos, porque no tiene por donde cogerlo.

Te voy a recomendar una práctica muy sencilla para estos casos, son tres cositas:

1. Crea variables para los valores PHP que irán dentro del contenido HTML
2. Crea todo el contenido HTML concatenado en una sola cadena, sin puntos ni nada, a no ser que dentro del bloque haya recorridos dentro de bucles y cosas así
3. Encierra todo dentro de comillas dobles `"` y para las etiquetas HTML que lleven comillas dobles, escápalas usando `\`, así escribirás todo de seguido, sin tener que concatenar con punto y cosas así.

Mira lo limpio que queda el código así, y si hay algún error lo notarás rápido (para `$row` y las otras variables he puesto datos imaginarioa para fines de demostración):

```
$row=array('usuario'=>'Pedro','dni'=>1,'id'=>20);
$usuario=$row['usuario'];
$dni=$row['dni'];
$id=$row['id'];
$estado2=2;

$contenidoHTML=   
    "<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
                <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">
            </head>
            <body>
                <fieldset>
                    <header>
                        <div class=\"container\" \"background-color:red;\" >
                    </header>
                    <br>
                <div style=\"float left\">USUARIO : <strong>$usuario</strong></div><br><br>
                <div style=\"float left\">DOCUMENTO : <strong>$dni</strong></div><br><br>
                    <a href=\"https://prueba.000webhostapp.com/insertDBYES.php?ide=$id&estado1=$id\"><button>CONFIRMAR</button></a>
                    <a href=\"https://prueba.000webhostapp.com/insertDBNO.php?ide=$id&estado2=$estado2\"><button>CANCELAR</button></a>
                </fieldset>
            </body>
        </html>";
echo $contenidoHTML;
```

**Salida:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                      <head>
                          <meta charset="utf-8">
                          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                      </head>
                      <body>
                          <fieldset>
                          <header>
                              <div class="container" "background-color:red;" >
                          </header>
                                <br>
                              <div style="float left">USUARIO : <strong>Pedro</strong></div><br><br>

                              <div style="float left">DOCUMENTO : <strong>1</strong></div><br><br>
                                <a href="https://prueba.000webhostapp.com/insertDBYES.php?ide=20&estado1=20"><button>CONFIRMAR</button></a>
                                <a href="https://prueba.000webhostapp.com/insertDBNO.php?ide=20&estado2=2"><button>CANCELAR</button></a>
                          </fieldset>
                      </body>
                    </html>
```

**NOTA:**

Revisa bien cómo estás creando tu HTML. Tenías una etiqueta `<center>` cerrada sin apertura (cabe decir que `center` es un elemento obsoleto), no estabas cerrando la etiqueta `<header>`, etc.